# Chrome is unable to load javascript

Tags: javascript

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CJ7Cw.png)

chrome always shows this dialogue before opening any new window, I can't figure out the problem. plz provide solution
I don't know anything about it and have seen this dialogue for the first time.

Comment: looks like a broken extension - what extensions have you added to Chrom?

Comment: I don't remember but can  turn off this extention to be loaded in chrome or remove it somehow?

Comment: `this extention` - which one? I can't see it, it's your browser - but yes, you are allowed to turn extensions off, or even remove them!